# MACRO execution steps in C

Tags: c, function, macros, order-of-execution

I wrote the following code to test MACRO functions:

```
#define err_exit(a, b) {fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",(a)); return (b); }

int func1(int a){
    if(a<50)
        err_exit("less than 50", a);
    if(a>50)
        err_exit("greater than 50", a);

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    fprintf(stdout, "\npop\n%d\n",func1(30));
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
less than 50

pop
30
```

But I was expecting this output:

```
pop
less than 50
30
```

Why is the text appearing before the `pop`? the function `func1()` is called after it!

How do macro replace instructions in the main code?

Comment: The call to `fprintf` **depends** on the result of `func1(3)`. How do you envision it starting before `func1` completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `func1(30)` is called, so that it can be executed, and the result should be produced. The `fprint()` in `main()` needs that result, so that it can print its stuff.

As `func1(30)` gets executed, the `fprintf()` of the macro gets executed, and "less than 50" gets printed. Now, the result of `func1(30)` is available.

`fprint()` of `main()` can proceed with the printing now (since it has everything it needs (i.e. the result of `func1(30)`).

It will print "pop", and then "30", as expected.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks!